# Convert a cell array of number into cell array of strings in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

I have the cell array of number matrices as follows:

```
  c= {[1,2,3,4] [1,2,4,3]   [1,3,2,4]}
```

Denoted that 1=A, 2=B, 3=C,4=D.How can I convert c into the cell array of strings as follows?

```
 s= {[A,B,C,D]  [A,B,D,C]   [A,C,B,D]}
```

And how can we generalize this rule such as 1 to 7 and A to G ... ?

Comment: Do you mean: `s = {['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you by `[A,B,C,D]` intend

```
['A','B','C','D'] => 'ABCD'
```

that is, to concatenate all of them to a single string, you could add `64` to each number (to get the proper ASCII-coding) and covert the numbers to a char.

```
s = cellfun(@(x) char(x + 64), c, 'UniformOutput', false);
s = 
     'ABCD'    'ABDC'    'ACBD'
```